# MySql Query If Field equals Field in different table update different field

Tags: mysql, insert, case

I have got two tables.  I want to update `MODEL` in table2 when `ITEM` in table1 equals `ITEM` in table2.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you do it like this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
           INNER JOIN table2 t2 
                ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col1, 
    t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Comment: actually, it's just a sample. the point there is how you can join tables in `UPDATE` query. you can set any values to any columns in table1. ex `t1.col1 = 'hello'` or you can set values based on the column on table2 like the above example :) @ToddN

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to perform an `UPDATE` on `table2` based on, presumably, foreign keys?

If that's right, this should work:

```
UPDATE
    table2
    JOIN table1
        ON table1.ITEM = table2.ITEM
SET
    MODEL = 'new value';
```

The table declaration in an `UPDATE` statement is the same as is specified in a `SELECT` statement - so you can use any type of `JOIN` that fits your table/data.
Docs for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you could add an actual query attempt, or something, that might be helpful.  Can you try something like the following:

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.ITEM = table1.ITEM SET MODEL = ?
```